# PL/SQL Cursor in Procedure doesn't work

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

Well, I have table Trainer and Certification(it's like degree or license) in my database and I am trying to create procedure, which for given id of trainer and new date will update the license of this person.

```
     CREATE TABLE Trainer
(
    trainer_id number(10) PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar2(15),
    surname varchar2(15),
    address varchar2(50),
    phone number(8),
    certification number(10)
);

INSERT INTO Trainer 
  VALUES(null, 'John', 'Climps', 'Blowing St, 134',18273643, 10);
INSERT INTO Trainer 
  VALUES(null, 'Bill', 'Spark', 'Academic St, 2', 28947384, 2);
INSERT INTO Trainer 
  VALUES(null, 'Olga', 'Redric', 'Captain Jack St, 7', 11862343, 6);
INSERT INTO Trainer 
  VALUES(null, 'Alex', 'Rose', 'Green St, 98', 18238633, 4);
INSERT INTO Trainer 
  VALUES(null, 'Monna', 'Lebindsky', 'Doge St, 1', 18685663, 5);
INSERT INTO Trainer 
  VALUES(null, 'Jack', 'Not', 'Tahon St, 76', 28941643, 3);
INSERT INTO Trainer 
  VALUES(null, 'Max', 'Scheight', 'Red Forrest St, 25', 28164064, 7);
INSERT INTO Trainer 
  VALUES(null, 'Emily', 'Ruby', 'Main St, 8', 1894636474, 8);
INSERT INTO Trainer 
  VALUES(null, 'Linda', 'Glaze', 'Yelecki St, 63', 18462343, 9);
INSERT INTO Trainer 
  VALUES(null, 'Merry', 'Gold', 'Main St, 101', 18434334, 1);

DROP TABLE Certification;
CREATE TABLE Certification
(
  certific_id number(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar2(50),
  description varchar2(1000),
  date_of_achieve varchar2(8),
  date_of_expire varchar2(8)
);

INSERT INTO Certification 
  VALUES(null, 'Fitness trainer', 'Course for a  beginner fitness trainer', 
  '09.10.15', '09.10.16');
INSERT INTO Certification 
  VALUES(null, 'Fitness trainer', 'Course for a  advanced fitness trainer', 
  '17.07.13', '13.07.16');
INSERT INTO Certification 
  VALUES(null, 'Football trainer', 'Degree of a football trainer', '11.01.12', 
  '01.10.16');
INSERT INTO Certification 
  VALUES(null, 'Tennis trainer', 'Degree of a  tennis trainer', '25.05.15', 
  '12.04.18');
INSERT INTO Certification 
  VALUES(null, 'Swimming trainer', 'Course for a swimming trainer for children',
  '18.10.14', '18.10.17');
INSERT INTO Certification 
  VALUES(null, 'Yoga master', 'Achieved after special yoga and medidation 
  cources in India','01.12.13', '15.04.16');
INSERT INTO Certification 
  VALUES(null, 'Sport master', 'Specialist in all sport activities', '14.03.14', 
  '14.03.18');
INSERT INTO Certification 
  VALUES(null, 'Fitness trainer', 'Master in workouts', '11.09.15', '11.03.18');
INSERT INTO Certification 
  VALUES(null, 'Equipment specialist', 'Master and instrucor of gym equipments', 
  '30.09.12', '30.01.16');
INSERT INTO Certification 
  VALUES(null, 'Boxer', 'Master in martial arts and boxing', '27.11.13', 
  '17.12.16');
```

Here is my procedure

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateTrainerCertificate(trainerID in number, nextDate in varchar)
AS
  no_trainer exception;
  no_name exception;
  invalid_date exception;
  no_certificate exception;

  tr_id number(10);
  tr_name varchar2(50);
  certific number(10);
  new_day_achieve varchar(8);
  Begin
  SELECT trainer_id INTO tr_id FROM Trainer WHERE trainer_id = trainerID;
  if tr_id is null then raise no_trainer;
  else
    SELECT name INTO tr_name FROM Trainer WHERE trainer_id = tr_id;
    if tr_name is null then no_name;
    else
      SELECT certification INTO certific FROM Trainer, Certification
      WHERE Trainer.certification = Certification.certific_id
      AND trainer_id = tr_id;    
      if certificate in null then raise no_certificate; 
      else
       SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD.MM.YY') INTO new_day_achieve 
       FROM DUAL; 
        if LENGTH(new_day_achieve) != 8 or LENGTH(nextDate) != 8 
        then raise invalid_date;
        else
          UPDATE Certification SET date_of_achieve = new_date_achieve,
                                   date_of_expire = nextDate
          WHERE certific_id = certific;

          DBMS_output.put_line(tr_name || ' updated certificate from ' 
          || new_day_achive || ' till ' || nextDate); 
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;

exception
  when no_trainer then dbms_output.put_line('No trainer found');
  when no_name then dbms_output.put_line('Error. Trainer without name. 
                                          Check table Trainer');
  when invalid_date then dbms_output.put_line('Invalid date format');
  when no_certificate then dbms_output.put_line('Trainer does not have any 
                                                certificate');
End;
/
```

Compile shows poorly understood errors

Answer (score 0):

The code for create table and insert data is wrong, it try to insert some null values in not null columns.

In the procedure there was some error for wrong variable name, this code compile for me:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE updateTrainerCertificate(trainerID in number, nextDate in varchar)
AS
  no_trainer exception;
  no_name exception;
  invalid_date exception;
  no_certificate exception;

  tr_id number(10);
  tr_name varchar2(50);
  certific number(10);
  new_day_achieve varchar(8);
  Begin
  SELECT trainer_id INTO tr_id FROM Trainer WHERE trainer_id = trainerID;
  if tr_id is null then raise no_trainer;
  else
    SELECT name INTO tr_name FROM Trainer WHERE trainer_id = tr_id;
    if tr_name is null then raise no_name;
    else
      SELECT certification INTO certific FROM Trainer, Certification
      WHERE Trainer.certification = Certification.certific_id
      AND trainer_id = tr_id;    
      if certific is null then raise no_certificate;
      else
       SELECT TO_CHAR(sysdate, 'DD.MM.YY') INTO new_day_achieve 
       FROM DUAL; 
        if LENGTH(new_day_achieve) != 8 or LENGTH(nextDate) != 8 
        then raise invalid_date;
        else
          UPDATE Certification SET date_of_achieve = new_day_achieve,
                                   date_of_expire = nextDate
          WHERE certific_id = certific;

          DBMS_output.put_line(tr_name || ' updated certificate from ' 
          || new_day_achieve || ' till ' || nextDate); 
        end if;
      end if;
    end if;
  end if;

exception
  when no_trainer then dbms_output.put_line('No trainer found');
  when no_name then dbms_output.put_line('Error. Trainer without name. 
                                          Check table Trainer');
  when invalid_date then dbms_output.put_line('Invalid date format');
  when no_certificate then dbms_output.put_line('Trainer does not have any 
                                                certificate');
End;
/
```

I've compiled it in SQLDeveloper 4.0.3.16, all errors are visible in a "compiler log" window and indicate the line of the error and the reason